# Нужна помощь в проверке кода

Tags: c++

Написал решение этой задачи:компьютер задает случайное число в десятичной системе счисления. Выводит его на экран и даёт пользователю задание:"Вам необходимо перевести данное число в двоичную систему счисления".в это время компьютер и пользователь переводят число,если результаты совпадают,то компьютер выводит сообщение,что пользователь правильно всё сделал,если нет,то у пользователя есть ещё один шанс.
Сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int binary, digit, decimal, test_num, user_num;
    //std::ostringstream str_decimal;
    srand(time(0));
    decimal = rand() % 1000;
    cout << "There is a number. You have to transfer it to binary one   " << decimal << endl;
    //str_decimal « decimal;
    //cout«str_decimal.str()«endl;
    digit = 1;
    while(decimal > 0)
    {
        test_num = test_num + (decimal % 2) * digit;
        decimal = decimal / 2;
        digit = digit * 10;
    }
    cin >> user_num;
    if (user_num = test_num)
        {
            cout << "You are right" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "You are wrong. One more time?)" << endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сразу бросается в глаза: `if (user_num = test_num)`... Дальше можно не смотреть.

Comment: @AnT, всякое ведь бывает, особенно в начале пути)